# Wordpress: single.php not getting current post data

Tags: php, wordpress

I've edited a Wordpress theme (twenty twenty one) to make my own theme instead, and I'm displaying posts in a grid. I've created a modal to show the selected post content and it works well. They do have a "next post" and "previous post" button and when I use the modal, it works well with the posts order in the admin panel. Everything happens inside index.php

However, whenever I go directly to a post url (then loading the single.php which is not used overall) it loads the content from the **first post created** (not even the first post by order, which can be manually adjusted by dragging the posts on the list in the admin panel). If I use the_title() and the_content(), it gets the wrong post data. What I managed to do this was to use "$page_id = get_queried_object_id()" and declare "get_the_title($page_id)" and "get_post_field('post_content', $page_id)" to get the correct post info. But it doesn't work when I try to apply this to the "get_next_post()" and "get_previous_post()", which are constantly using that first created post as reference.

Here's my code for single.php (the content actually goes inside modal.php, but doesn't work also if it's directly on single.php

```
<?php
/**
* The template for displaying all single posts

*/
$page_id = get_queried_object_id();

get_header();
?>
<span id="page-id" page-ref="<?php echo $page_id; ?>">
</span>
<?php
get_template_part('template-parts/grid'); ?>
</div>

<div class="modal-wrapper">
    <div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal">
        <h1>
            <?php the_title(); ?>

        </h1>
        <?php get_template_part('template-parts/modal'); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="reveal-modal-bg"></div>
</div>



<?php

get_footer();
```

From what I've researched, it seems that maybe the single.php is not accessing the loop?
But why isn't "the_title()" getting the current post title from single.php, but the first post instead?

Thanks

Edit: grid.php (which runs the loop on the main page)

```html
<section class="works">
    <div class="cat-menu">
        <ul>
            <a href="<?php
            echo get_home_url(); ?>">
                <li class="js-filter-item">Todos</li>
            </a>
            <?php

            $categories = get_categories();
            foreach ($categories as $cat):
                $category_link = get_category_link($cat->term_id); ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $category_link; ?>">
                    <li class="js-filter-item" data-category="<?= $cat->term_id ?>"><?= $cat->name; ?></li>
                </a>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-wrapper">
        <div class="js-filter grid">

            <?php

            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'posts_per_page' => 6

            );
            $query = new WP_Query($args);
            if ($query->have_posts()) {

                // Load posts loop.
                while ($query->have_posts()) {
                    $query->the_post();

                    get_template_part('template-parts/content/content', get_theme_mod('display_excerpt_or_full_post', 'excerpt'));

                }
                // Previous/next page navigation.
            


            } else {

                // If no content, include the "No posts found" template.
                get_template_part('template-parts/content/content-none');

            } ?>

        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: `single.php` definitely uses the loop. What's in your `template-parts/grid`? I'm going to guess you might be using `new WP_Query()` or changing the default loop to output your grid posts, so you are essentially high-jacking the loop. Just a guess. Show us the code in that template part.

Comment: @disinfor yes, I did use that. But unfortunately I don't know php/wordpress that much to figure out why this would be a problem. Just updated the question with the grid.php

Comment: Yep, you are overwriting the loop so you’ll never get the current post content. The question is **why** are you doing this on the single.pho template?

Comment: @disinfor I did it because I want the posts content to be displayed as a modal div over the grid. So, whenever you open the direct url to the post as in website.com/post5, you would still get the post as the modal, so I had to create the grid again. To summarize, I wanted the single.php page to behave almost as if it was the index.php itself, but with the selected post open as a modal. Which right now by explaining it seems to be conceptually very wrong

Comment: btw yes, I removed the template-parts/grid from the single.php and it worked

Comment: Yeah, so you'll need to change your approach on `single.php` if you want all posts to show below the current post content, which would be in a modal. You essentially can't reuse the same template parts - your `grid` template should use a `new WP_Query`, but I would suggest renaming the variable that holds that to something like `$grid_posts` so there's not a conflict with global WP variables. Then you'll also need to use `wp_reset_query()` in that template. Then in the modal simply use the regular loop query.